# Checking a lot of URLs to see if they return 200. What's the cleverest way?

Tags: python, http, curl, head

I need to check a lot (~10 million) of URLs to see if they exist (return 200). I've written the following code to do this per-URL, but to do all of the URLs will take approximately forever.

```
def is_200(url):             
    try:
        parsed = urlparse(url)
        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(parsed.netloc)
        conn.request("HEAD", parsed.path)
        res = conn.getresponse()
        return res.status == 200
    except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
        raise e
    except:
        return False
```

The URLs are spread across about a dozen hosts, so it seems like I should be able to take advantage of this to pipeline my requests and reduce connection overhead. How would you build this? I'm open to any programming/scripting language.

Comment: Maybe node.js would help here, as it does asynchronous I/O, which scales better than blocking threads. Also, you could use a cluster of machines for this, if available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [urllib3](http://code.google.com/p/urllib3/). It supports per-host connection re-using.
Additionally using multiple processes/threads or async I/O would be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the link. urllib3 looks nice.

Answer (score 2):

## All of this is in Python, version 3.x.

I would create worker threads that check for 200. I'll give an example. The threadpool (put in threadpool.py):

```
# http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577187-python-thread-pool/

from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

class Worker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, tasks):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.tasks = tasks
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            func, args, kargs = self.tasks.get()
            try: func(*args, **kargs)
            except Exception as exception: print(exception)
            self.tasks.task_done()

class ThreadPool:
    def __init__(self, num_threads):
        self.tasks = Queue(num_threads)
        for _ in range(num_threads): Worker(self.tasks)

    def add_task(self, func, *args, **kargs):
        self.tasks.put((func, args, kargs))

    def wait_completion(self):
        self.tasks.join()
```

Now, if `urllist` contains your urls then your main file should be along the lines of this:

```
numconns = 40
workers = threadpool.ThreadPool(numconns)
results = [None] * len(urllist)

def check200(url, index):
    results[index] = is_200(url)

for index, url in enumerate(urllist):
    try:
        workers.add_task(check200, url, index)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Shutting down application, hang on...")
        workers.wait_completion()

        break
```

Note that this program scales with the other suggestions posted here, this is only dependent on `is_200()`.

Comment: Thanks for the thread pool implementation. Unfortunately, I'm limited to python 2.5 on this system, which put me off from your answer initially, but the code works fine on 2.5 as well if you change the one import to `from Queue import Queue` and use `self.setDaemon(True)` in the `Worker` constructor.